# Changing value of global javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm attempting to change the value of a global variable inside a javascript function, however, the value does not seem to be taken, and I'm not sure why. (Admittedly, I am not an experienced javascript person.) Here is my code:

```
var title_chart = "";

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Number of Entries');

  jQuery.getJSON('/data/stats.json', function(chart_data) {
    title_chart = chart_data.chart_title;
    jQuery.each(chart_data.stats, function(index, value){
      data.addRows(1);
      data.setValue(index, 0, value.chart_label);
    });
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 450, height: 300, title: title_chart});

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which global variable? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You need to use window.variable="value  you want to set" to set the value of global javascript variable see the link for you reference https://www.javatpoint.com/oprweb/test.jsp?filename=jsglobalvariable2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getJSON` is asynchronous.  Do this instead:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/data/stats.json', function(chart_data) {
  var title_chart = chart_data.chart_title;
  jQuery.each(chart_data.stats, function(index, value){
    data.addRows(1);
    data.setValue(index, 0, value.chart_label);
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 450, height: 300, title: title_chart});
});
```

The issue is that `getJSON` returns immediately.  Only later, when the request completes, is your callback called.  In the meantime, `chart.draw` may have already run.  By moving this code into the callback function, we ensure it runs at the right time.  Also note that we can eliminate the global.